# Why can't I convert the architecture in an application?

Tags: assembly, architecture

Applications, that run on a x32 machine, have assembler commands that only work on a x32 machine. A ARM machine has got other commands. Why cant i convert the "assembler commands" from the application to make it run on an other architecture?

Comment: "Why cant i convert ..." is solely opinion based question and not related to programming... I can't fly F-15 but it does not mean much - there are plenty of people who can say it is trivial.

Comment: What is x32? Do you mean x86 or IA-32? As far as converting assembly code (or even machine code) between different architectures goes; sure, it can be done, but it takes a lot of work. And mapping the instructions 1:1 probably won't do you much good, since the code will be written to run in a specific environment (HW and OS).

Comment: Of course you can, you have emulators that run one ISA over another. There's usually a large overhead in that process though, for the runtime env and also since most of the optimizations done at compilation are wrong and don't translate well at the single instruction level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, it's easy: any [Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) system can compute anything any other Turing-complete system can.  In practice, it's a lot more complicated.

The big one is the software environment.  Almost every program out there assumes that it'll be interacting with an operating system that provides a wide range of functionality: abstracting away the details of hardware access, isolating the program from others running on the same machine, providing common code libraries, and so on.  After you've translated your program to the new instruction set, you still need to provide the supporting software.

The other major one is hardware.  A computer is more than just a CPU, and a program makes certain assumptions, either explicit or implicit, about the other parts.  For example, [the order in which bytes are put together into larger datatypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) varies, and a program that performs bit-level operations will have trouble if it goes from a big-endian machine to a little-endian one, or vice-versa.  There can also be restrictions on memory access, eg. a target system might require memory reads to be [aligned on a multiple of four bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment), while the original system had no such requirements.  There can also be more subtle problems, for example, the x86 FPU uses 80-bit precision for all floating-point calculations, even on lower precision numbers.  A program that relies on that extra internal precision would fail on a system with a 64-bit FPU.

The x86 architecture in particular has a feature that makes converting programs difficult: the instructions vary in size and alignment.  This means you cannot, in the general case, look at a program and immediately tell what instructions it consists of.  A one-byte shift between the assumed and actual instruction alignment, such as you might find in an anti-piracy trap or a compact-coding demonstration, can mean a wild shift in what the program does.

There are programs that let you convert a program from one architecture to another, but they typically either use [dynamic recompilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_recompilation) to re-write the program as it runs, or they fully emulate the original system, re-interpreting each instruction as it comes up for execution.  In either case, the user needs to provide the software environment for the program to run in.